# Can I use the KVV (Karlsruher Verkehrsverbund) regiomove app without an address in Germany, Austria, Switzerland, or France?

Tags: germany, public-transport, mobile-apps

I'm visiting Baden-Baden for little under a week, and it would be convenient to be able to use the public transport system to get around. As such, I downloaded  their app and verified my phone number and email, but then I hit a roadblock: the app asks for my name and address. Name is fine, but address is a problem as they only allow Germany, Austria, Switzerland, and France as countries. I don't have an address in any of these countries. I tried calling their support, but he was unable to do anything and instead suggested I go to their customer support office in Karlsruhe, which is over an hour away from where I'm at. Their English website doesn't even seem to mention the app[1](https://www.kvv.de/en/tickets.html), which is understandable given that the app doesn't seem to have an English translation. Is there any way I can use this app without having to have an address in Germany, Austria, Switzerland, or France? Or, alternatively, some other way of buying tickets for public transport in this area from my phone?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can put your hotel/AirBnB address

Comment: This seems to be part of their **regiomove** system which includes booking of tickets. They state that the address is needed for any future contact/contract. If you have a hotel address use that. Their hotline is +4972161075885.

Comment: More phone numbers: https://www.kvv.de/service/kundenzentren.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, the Regiomove app sucks, but there are alternatives: you can buy KVV tickets through Deutsche Bahn's [DB Navigator app](https://www.bahn.com/en/booking-information/db-navigator-app), which lets you select an address in a country basically anywhere. And there's also the [Fairtiq app,](https://www.kvv.de/fahrkarten/verkauf/online/kvvluftlinie.html) which doesn't require an address at all (note that you have to have location and internet always on for Fairtiq, as it calculates the fare based on actual distance travelled).

If you require further assistance, there's a Baden-Baden public transport customer centre at [Augustaplatz](https://www.kvv.de/service/kundenzentren.html).